# Multiple plots per page from for loop ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to use `multiplot` to write multiple plots per page from `ggplot` within a for loop. However, the PDF only shows a total of two plots (instead of four) on separate pages (instead of two plots per page), based on the below example dataset.

This is what I currently have:

```
> CohData
     Name ScenID ScenName Year VarName Units value
1  Site01      0     Hind 2000     ANC ueq/L 35.34
2  Site01      1       BC 2020     ANC ueq/L 32.86
3  Site01      1       BC 2040     ANC ueq/L 32.25
4  Site02      0     Hind 2000     ANC ueq/L 28.23
5  Site02      1       BC 2020     ANC ueq/L 45.01
6  Site02      1       BC 2040     ANC ueq/L 57.86
7  Site01      0     Hind 2000      pH        5.93
8  Site01      1       BC 2020      pH        5.86
9  Site01      1       BC 2040      pH        5.85
10 Site02      0     Hind 2000      pH        6.40
11 Site02      1       BC 2020      pH        6.63
12 Site02      1       BC 2040      pH        6.75

library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)

## Iterate plots and write to PDF
pdf("plots.pdf")
CohData_nohind <- subset(CohData, ScenID > 0)
stream_vars <- list("ANC", "pH")
for (i in unique(CohData_nohind$ScenID)){
  subdata1 <- subset(CohData_nohind, ScenID == i)
  ScenName <- unique(subdata1$ScenName)
  subdata1 <- subset(CohData, ScenID == i | ScenID == 0)
  for (j in stream_vars){
    subdata2 <- subset(subdata1, VarName == j)
    units <- unique(subdata2$Units)
    for (k in unique(subdata2$Name)){
      subdata3 <- subset(subdata2, Name == k)

      if (j=='ANC'){
        plots <- list()
        p <- ggplot(subdata3, aes(x = Year, y = value)) + geom_line() + expand_limits(y=c(0,100)) + 
          ggtitle(paste0(as.character(ScenName),":\n", as.character(k))) + ylab(paste0(j, " (", units, ")"))
        plots[[i]] <- p

      } else if (j=='pH'){
        plots <- list()
        p <- ggplot(subdata3, aes(x = Year, y = value)) + geom_line() + expand_limits(y=c(3,7)) +
          ggtitle(paste0(as.character(ScenName),":\n", as.character(k))) + ylab(paste0(j, " (", units, ")"))
        plots[[i]] <- p

      }
    }
    multiplot(plotlist = plots, cols = 2)
  }
}
dev.off()
```

The full dataset has five "Names" and I'd like to have five plots per page (one for each "Name"). Any suggestions for achieving this?

Comment: You might want to check out `plot_grid::cowplot` instead of `multiplot`.  I find it easier to use

Comment: Also check out `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package. Either way, lay out the plots first and then save to a PDF file.

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting `plots` each time through the inner loop. I'm not positive, but browsing through your code, it looks like you want to initialize `plots=list()` before the outer loop and then name the elements of `plots` with unique names, something like `plots[[paste(i,j,k,sep="_")]] = p`, so that you won't overwrite previous elements.

Comment: I want to save each set of `plots` as they are made (somewhere). I am trying to write them to the PDF each time through the loop, then overwrite plots to store the next set, then write those. Maybe it is better to use a temporary storage location, then write them all at once. I am not sure how to do this though.

Comment: Then, if using `grid.arrange`, you could do something like `grid.arrange(grobs=plots, ncol=5)` or, if using `cowplot`, `plot_grid(plotlist=plots, ncol=5)`.

Comment: Okay, but you'll still need to initialize `plots` in the right place. The current code resets `plots` to an empty list every time your `if ... else` statement is called.

Comment: @eipi10 Where should the `grid.arrange(grobs=plots, ncol=5)` be placed?

Comment: Well, I was assuming you'd plot the whole list all at once. Instead, run `grid.arrange` whenever you have all the plots that you want in a given layout. If you're creating say, four plots that you want to lay out together, run `grid.arrange` after you've created them. Then `plots` gets reinitialized the next time through the loop(s) and you do the whole thing again.

Comment: Also have a look at `marrangeGrob` from `gridExtra`, to print multiple plots over multiple pages

Comment: @user20650 Indeed, it seems I need something like `marrangeGrob` to plot over multiple pages because the full `plot` list is all being written to a single page, which doesn't work with my large dataset. I am not familiar with `marrageGrob` so it may take some time to implement.

Comment: okay @viridius , quick example. `l <- replicate(4, ggplot(), simplify = F) ;
m <- marrangeGrob(l, nrow=2, ncol=1) ; ggsave("test1.pdf", m)` will have the four plots over two pages. So just try to arrange your plots in a list first.

Comment: I have `marrangeGrob(plots, nrow=2, ncol=2)` working on my dataset, which gives four plots per page, but I need five. Can this be done with `marrageGrob`?

Comment: How do you want the five plots arranged ? Do you want 3 rows and 2 columns, with the last plot left empty?

Comment: I have used `layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,0), 3, 2, byrow = TRUE))` with the standard `plot` function, but not sure how to do this with `marrangeGrob` and `ggplot`

Comment: `l <- replicate(10, ggplot(), simplify = F) ;  arr <- rbind(c(1, 2),  c(3, 4), c(5, NA)) ;  m = marrangeGrob(lapply(list(1:5, 6:10), function(x) arrangeGrob(grobs=l[x], layout_matrix = arr)), nrow=1, ncol=1)` ;

Comment: But, I would ask how to do this in a separate question, as the gridExtra package author is acitve on SO, and will come up with something clever / concise.